# Is it possible to view a PowerPoint slide show at 100% zoom?

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint, microsoft-powerpoint-2013

When I start a slide show in PowerPoint 2013, it is displayed in full screen with the slides zoomed to fill the screen.

Is it possible to view a slideshow with the slides "actual size", i.e. the same size as when editing them at 100% zoom?

Comment: That is not how the program is designed. Slideshows are intended to be full screen. If you give us more details of what you are trying to accomplish (including screenshots) we can try to help you.

Comment: I assume you want a solution where the photo is not scaled and borders are added as you please, correct? If so, PowerPoint is not going to be the tool of choice. You can use the Windows Photo Viewer for that end though. It also has the slideshow option, and you can manually slide past each photos in fullscreen, making it show 100% with borders around.

Comment: Try Slide Show | Set up show and choose "Browsed by an individual (window)".  You can adjust the size of the window after starting the slide show.  That said, sometimes it's more useful to state the problem you want to solve rather than asking how to accomplish one possible solution you've arrived at. IOW, what exactly are you trying to do here?

Answer (score 0):

You can adjust the size of the slides to fit to the screen size parameters. You can even select a custom size. Please try the following and see if it works.

1. Normally, in PowerPoint 2013/2016, the size is set to 16:9 (widescreen).
2. First, make sure you're in Normal view (on the View tab, click Normal). Then click the Design tab, and click Slide Size in the Customize group. The Slide Size button is also available in Slide Master view on the Slide Master tab.
3. Click the desired size of click Custom Slide Size to open up the Slide Size dialog box. From here, make necessary changes and save the settings. You can also save these themes.
4. For more, please visit [this page](https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/Change-the-size-of-your-slides-040a811c-be43-40b9-8d04-0de5ed79987e).

If you want to set the size during the presentation instead, or even while viewing it (on a single monitor). While doing a presentation,  you could use the Enhanced Presenter's View options. There are few options with this utility too.

1. If you cannot see get into this view, right click anywhere on the playing deck
2. Click **Show Presenter View**.